# highcharts in new window with ajax and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, charts, highcharts

I've seen others similar asks but not one with ajax and jquery, hope don't repeat ask.

I need load the charts in the new window 'estadisticasMultiples.html', there is the div with tag charts but the highcharts error says "rendering div not found" (http://www.highcharts.com/errors/13)

how i could render the charts in new window, inside div with charts tag?

Grateful for the help you can give me.

```
   function ver_grafica(var1, var2, var3){

        $.post('ver_grafica.php', 
            {
                var1:var1,
                var2:var2,
                var3:var3
            }
        )

        .done(function (data)
            {
                var datos = JSON.parse(data);

                var options = {
                    chart: {
                        renderTo: 'charts',
                        width: '800',
                        height: '550'
                    },

                    title: {
                            text: 'Histórico de '+datos['nombre']
                    },

                    subtitle: {
                        text: 'durante el mes de '+mesesNombre[parseInt(datos['mes']-1)]+' de '+datos['anio']
                    },

                    yAxis: {
                        title: {
                            text: datos['unidad']
                        }
                    },

                    xAxis: {
                        tickInterval: 1
                    },

                    legend: {
                        layout: 'vertical',
                        align: 'right',
                        verticalAlign: 'middle'
                    },

                    plotOptions: {
                        series: {
                            pointStart: 1,
                            marker: {
                                enabled: false
                            },
                        },
                    },

                    tooltip: {
                        formatter: function() {
                            return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                            '<i>Día '+this.x +': </i><b>'+this.y+'</b>';
                        }
                    },

                    legend: {
                        align: 'center',
                        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
                        layout: 'horizontal', // default
                        itemDistance: 50
                    },

                    colors: ['#2f7ed8', '#FF7777', '#FFC077', '#FFC077', '#FF7777'],

                    series: [{
                            name: datos['nombre'],
                            data: datos['param'],
                            marker: { 
                                symbol: 'circle'
                            },
                            zIndex: 6
                        }, {
                            name: 'Niveles máximo y mínimo',
                            data: datos['max'],
                            marker: { 
                                symbol: 'false'
                            },
                            zIndex: 1,
                            enableMouseTracking: false,
                        }
                    ]
                };

                var nuevaVentana = window.open('estadisticasMultiples.html', '_blank');

                var graficas = new Highcharts.Chart(options);



            }
        )

        .fail(function() 
            {
                alert("Falló al intentar enviar los datos");
            }
        );
    }
```

estadisticasMultiples.html

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div name='charts' id='charts'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a chart not in the opened window, but in the window you're making ajax request which does not have the specified container. You can the element from the opened window and set it in the options:

```
var nuevaVentana = window.open('estadisticasMultiples.html', '_blank');
var graficas;

nuevaVentana.onload = function () {
  options.chart.renderTo = nuevaVentana.document.getElementById('charts');
  graficas = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
}
```

If you have scripts not in the opened window, the animation might be glitchy, I would move the script for rendering the chart to `estadisticasMultiples.html` file and pass the options object to the opened window via localStore or global variable

estadisticasMultiples.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div name='charts' id='chart'></div>

    <script>
        var options = window.options;

        if (options) {
            Highcharts.chart(options);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

ver_grafica:

```
   function ver_grafica(var1, var2, var3){

    $.post('ver_grafica.php', 
        {
            var1:var1,
            var2:var2,
            var3:var3
        }
    )

    .done(function (data)
        {
            var datos = JSON.parse(data);

            var options = {...}

            var nuevaVentana = window.open('estadisticasMultiples.html', '_blank');

            nuevaVentana.options = options;
        }
    )

    .fail(function() 
        {
            alert("Falló al intentar enviar los datos");
        }
    );
```

Comment: Many thanks @morganfree, your codet works perfectly.